# tikzpicture problem aligning shapes and getting arrows right

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I failed to get this work as expected:

```
\begin{frame}{\textarabic{\emph{دیکشنری}}}
     \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[approach/.style={draw,very thick, text width=8em,
            text centered, minimum height=2.5em,rounded corners=3ex},
         idea/.style={draw, very thick, circle,text width=3em,
            text centered, minimum height=2.5em},
         connections/.style={<->,draw=black!30,line width=3pt,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt},
      ]

      % Draw diagram elements
      \node (idea) [idea,draw=blue,fill=blue!20]  {\textarabic{\textbf{دیکشنری مناسب}}};
      \pause
         \node (verbal) [approach,above=of idea]  {\textarabic{\textbf{استخراج ویژگی‌های برجسته‌ی کلاسی از داده‌ها}}};
         \node (formular)[approach,below=of idea] {\textarabic{\textbf{تنک کننده}}};

         % Draw arrows between elements
         \draw[connections] (idea) -- (formular) ;
         \draw[connections] (idea) -- (verbal);
         \draw[connections] (verbal.west) to[out=80,in=60](formular.west) ;
         \draw[connections] (verbal.east) to[out=80,in=60](formular.east) ;
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

I want the arrows to look like this (not red, the same grey color) and the whole thing aligned center:

[image]

I also want the three shapes to appear one by one, but I really don't know how to use `pause` or any other functions here.

Comment: You can adjust the angle of the arrow by adjusting `[out=80,in=60]` which define the in and outgoing angles of the arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of topic: providing only sniped of your code, is not very helpful to anyone who would be willing to help you.

In your case you have problem with geometry. your definition of `out` and`in` angle is wrong according what you like to have ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{arabic text}
     \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
  approach/.style = {draw,very thick, text width=8em,
                     text centered, minimum height=2.5em,rounded corners=3ex},
       idea/.style = {draw, very thick, circle,text width=3em,
                      text centered, minimum height=2.5em},
connections/.style = {<->,draw=black!30,line width=3pt,
                      shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt},
                        ]
      % Draw diagram elements
\node (idea) [idea,draw=blue,fill=blue!20]  {arabic text};
      \pause
\node (verbal) [approach,above=of idea] {more arabic text};
\node (formular)[approach,below=of idea] {more arabic text};
% Draw arrows between elements
\draw[connections] (idea) -- (formular) ;
\draw[connections] (idea) -- (verbal);
\draw[connections] (verbal.west) to[out=210,in=150](formular.west);% changed angles
\draw[connections] (verbal.east) to[out=330,in=30](formular.east) ;% changed angles
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate how you get the angles right?

Comment: angle is determined with direction how the curve leave and come to a coordinate.  Left one leave `verbal.west` by (`out`) angle 210 degrees and come to  `formular.west` at (`in`) angle 150 degrees. Values I estimated. You can select them different. Some experimets will give you a filling for estimation of good selection.